# No cast for observer pattern using generics

Tags: java, generics, design-patterns, observer-pattern, unchecked-cast

I was looking to implement an subject-observer pattern where the subject provides its self to the observers when notifying.

```
public class Subject<T extends Subject> {

    /** suporting stuff for subject */

    private List<Observer<T>> observers = new ArrayList<>();

    protected void doNotify() {
        for(Observer<T> observer : observers) {
            /** This is the line where it gets interesting */
            observer.update((T)this);
        }
    }
}
```

Practically, this work, however, the compiler gives a *Unchecked cast* warning on the `observer.update((T)this);` line.

When reading a bit about this, the compiler is right (surprise surprise) and its even considered as smelly code, as you can write code that actually triggers the *ClassCastException*.

Now I am looking for a solution that isn't smelly and rock solid. However, the thought that an observer does not need to look for the subject that it is observing is something I really like. Also, I don't really like the observers need to do the cast themselves in their `update()`. Do you have any suggestion on how to on this one?

---

### Edit

My observer is declared as interface like this:

```
public interface Observer<T> {
    void update(T subject);
}
```

Comment: In your case, your `observer` is a consumer, therefore you should use `super`: `private List<Observer<? super T>> observers = ...;`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is PECS (Producer Extends Consumer Super)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super)

Comment: I don't think so. The post you are referring to is about how to accept a collection as function parameter. I am not looking on how to accept a collection, but rather to provide a pointer to `this` to each item in a collection. The problem I am trying to solve is the cast from `this` to the underlying child class (i.e. `return (T)this`).

Comment: You can extrapolate the meaning from the example: If a generic class is a producer, use `extends` on the generic type. If a generic class is a consumer, use `super` on the generic type. Your `observer` is a consumer. Therefore, use `super`.

Comment: How about `class Subject<T extends Subject<T>>`?

Comment: Oh you are right, the exact definition is a little more complex: `private List<Observer<? super Subject<T>>> observers = new ArrayList<>();` (`T` itself is not sufficient) (plus what @AndyTurner said, since you are basically using raw types right now)

Comment: @AndyTurner this alone is not sufficient to get rid of the warning.

Comment: @Turing85 that is true. But there isn't actually a way to get rid of the warning, because there is nothing to constrain the class to be exactly self-bounded.

Comment: @AndyTurner you can constrain `observers`. But then again, without further knowledge of the `Observer` class/interface, I do not know whether my suggestion is feasible.

Comment: @Turing85 it has nothing to do with `Observer` itself. It's like the fact that you can write a class `class SomeClass implements Comparable<SomeOtherClass>`: it doesn't make sense to do this directly, but it doesn't mean you *can't*.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172836/discussion-between-turing85-and-andy-turner).

Comment: @AndyTurner I tried the `Subject<T extends Subject<T>>` and it did not resolve the warning.

Comment: I don't see any reason for your Subject to be generic. If what is passed to the observers is the subject itself, then just use a non-generic Subject class, and accept observers of type `Observer<? super Subject>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Foreword: I would suggest NOT to use generics- because by forcing the clients (Observers) to know about the exact type of a Subject, (as opposed to having a non-generic Subject class), you cannot eg. subscribe the same Observer to multiple Subjects (of different types).

Anyway, there is a way to have type-safety .

---

In the call `observer.update((T)this)` you want two things: you want to pass `this` to observers; and you also want for `this` to be of type `T`.

At that point, `this` is not guaranteed to be of type `T` of course- it is of type Subject. But "this" will be of type T in a concrete `Subject` class. So substitute `this` with `getThisSubject()` and move it down in the hierarchy. In code:

```
package stackOv;
import java.util.*;

abstract class Subject<T extends Subject<T>> {
  private List<Observer<T>> observers = new ArrayList<>();
  // returns a reference of this, of type T
  protected abstract T getThisSubject();
  protected void doNotify() {
    for(Observer<T> observer : observers) {
      observer.update(getThisSubject());
    }
  }
  public void addObserver(Observer<T> obs) {
    observers.add(obs);
  }
}

class SubjectA extends Subject<SubjectA> { 
  @Override
  protected SubjectA getThisSubject() {
    return this;
  }
}

interface Observer<T> {
  void update(T subject);
}

class UseSubject {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SubjectA sub = new SubjectA();

    Observer<SubjectA> obs = new Observer<SubjectA>() {
      @Override
      public void update(SubjectA subject) {
        //and here we have a reference to the right type
        System.out.println("subj=" + subject);
      }
    };

    sub.addObserver(obs);
    sub.doNotify();
  }
}
```

---

Let me stress that we are coupling `Observer` types with `Subject` types; they really are in a one-to-one relationship. A way to avoid this is declaring `Subject` non-generic, and

```
interface Observer {
  void update(Subject subject);
}
```

plus using visitor or other patterns. (but this reply is long enough already).

Comment: I like this approach, its simple and effective. I dont really like the thought of implementing the `getThisSubject()` in all concrete subjects, but I also think that there is not a better alternative.

Comment: To respond on whether it's a good idea, you say you can't register at observers with other type, and that is just half true, I think. You could implment multiple observers with different types. Also, you say the types are coupled and that is true. However, observing a class of unknown or abstract type does not make sense in real life. Usually you are not really intereseted in if there was a change, but rather what the change was. Hence, if the `update` passes an abstract type Subject you still need a cast to the type you are observing before you can figure out what the change was.